# How to hide Characters when Call Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, phone-call, uiapplication

I have a URL for conference call from iPhone,

```
tel:1600123456,,,,,,1234#
```

This is the conference call number followed by the Passcode.
While calling the whole number and characters are displayed.
How can I hide the ',,' in the call.

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, i don't think there is an option to do that..

Answer (score 1):

That's managed by the system. I don't believe there's any way to override it.